# Custom layouts for responsive site page

Tags: theming

We're converting a site to be responsive and have decided to use Adaptive Theme. But the client insists on a unique layout for the Front page that does not fit into Adaptive's method of stacking sidebars. In principle I need a layout program like Panels or Display Suite that lets you create two layouts, and then decides which one to use depending on the device. I'm a coder and can do this myself with a page callback, or I suppose in the front page template, but was hoping for another solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the theme key module might be just what you need. From the module's page:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's
>   theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:

- individually-styled channels
- a front-page / "splash" screen a
- date/time-selected Christmas
- theme mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
- special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
- content, user, or role -specific themes indicating your
- environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … ) testing your
- redesign safely on a live server

And many more. https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey